# Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported exception on 64Bit visio

Tags: 64-bit, activex, visio

I am extending the compatibility of my application from visio 32-bit to visio 64 bit. I am using visio 2013 on win7(64) machine. I am getting exception of windowless ActiveX control is not supported. I have tried  both
[KB 980533](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980533) and Readme sample file provided with Visi SDK for buidling solution for 64-bit system on this location   \VisSDK\Samples\Readme Samples 64bit.htm. I have tried DEP solution but not working.

**STACK TRACE:**

```
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EnsureWindowPresent()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.InPlaceActivate()
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.TransitionUpTo(Int32 state)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.CreateHandle()
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.Control.CreateControl(Boolean fIgnoreVisible)
   at System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.EndInit()
```

{"Unable to get the window handle for the 'AxDrawingControl' control. Windowless ActiveX controls are not supported."}

System Info:

OS:    Windows 7 64 bit
Visio:   Visio 2013 64 bit
Target Platform:.Net 4.5, Any CPU
Interop: AxInterop.Microsoft.Office.VisOcx.dll (created on the 32 bit machine)
Visio Drawing Control:    VISOCX.DLL 64 bit (yes, it's registered)
IDE:   Visual Studio 2013 Professional

Answer (score 2):

I finally got our solution to work using 64-bit.

The magic was that I realized that I didn't actually need the control in the XAML; so what I ended up doing was removing the control from the XAML page, and instantiating it from the constructor of the .xaml.cs code.

So: follow the instructions in [this link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms742735.aspx) to build a custom control. I *think* you have to build using the 64-bit version of MSBuild.exe as noted in [the link you provided](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/980533).  This is apparently only required when you are creating the custom control; I was able to build the solution directly from VS (but it also worked correctly when built by MSBuild, so it works in automated builds, as well).

### Creating a custom control

1. Create a new custom control project named VisioAxControl in a build environment with 32-bit Visio installed
2. In VS Designer, drag/drop the Visio Drawing control from the toolbox to the form, inside a WindowsFormsHost. You may need to add this control to the toolbox (right-click toolbox, "Choose items...").  Performing this step causes VS to create (and add a reference to) a new DLL, "Microsoft Visio 15.0 Drawing Control Type Library" of type     AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx. This DLL is put into the /obj/Release directory under the project, but will be copied to /bin when you build if you simply select the reference and set "Copy local" to "true".
3. Open the code-behind and change the scope of the control to `public` and refactor:rename it from `axDrawingControl1` to `AxVisioControl` (most importantly, don't forget `this.AxVisioControl.Name = "AxVisioControl";`)
4. Build the project to create the WPF control DLL for the final x86/32-bit solution build
5. For your x86/32-bit solution, copy & reference both `VisioAxControl.dll` and `AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll` into a folder somewhere in the solution.

   #### Building the 64-bit control
6. Save, copy/move, and open the custom control project in a build environment with 64-bit Visio installed
7. Change the build platform to x64
8. Open an administrator command prompt, cd to your project directory
9. Run `MSBuild_Path\MSBuild.exe /p:Configuration=Release /p:Platform=x64 your_project_file_name` (for me, MSBuild_Path is C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\MSBuild.exe) to build the custom control project to create the WPF control DLL for use in the final x64 solution build

### Including in your 64-bit project

1. Copy & reference `/bin/Release/VisioAxControl.dll` and `/obj/Release/AxMicrosoft.Office.Interop.VisOcx.dll`.
2. In the XAML of your form, add a `<WindowsFormsHost name="MyWindowsFormsHost"></WindowsFormsHost>` control.
3. In the code-behind of the XAML, in the constructor:

   ```
   using VisioAxControl;
   public DesignView()
   {
       InitializeComponent();
       var avc = new VisioAxControl() { Name = "vControl" };
       this.MyWindowsFormsHost.Child = avc;
       this._avc = avc.AxVisioControl;  // for later reference, such as adding shapes
   }
   ```
4. Save & Build your project!